# ESP8266 only responds to AT and AT+GMR

Tags: esp8266

I purchased a pack of esp8266 ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PA3UQNI/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PA3UQNI)) and a usb to serial converter ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01FUA2BBU/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FUA2BBU)) from amazon. I hooked them up and attempted to use the Arduino serial monitor to communicate with the esp8266. Here are the commands I used and the responses I got:
    AT

```
OK
AT+GMR

+GMR: 7.80.5.0

OK
AT+RST

ERROR
```

My current setup is (RX on serial -> TX on esp) and (TX on serial-> RX on esp), although I have also tried them swapped. I have tried running the serial monitor at 115200, 57600, and 9600 baud and they all put out the same response. I have tried with both boards. I am currently running the esp8266 off of two AA batteries. All grounds are connected, CH_PD is connected to Vsupply with a 10k resistor, RST is connected to ground with a 3k resistor.

I have not done anything with the firmware and I have not tried any other serial monitor.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can try to get these to work.

Comment: Your question is wrong, your ESP is responding to AT+RST, it just doesn't understand what AT+RST means. Have you tried any other documented AT commands?

Comment: I have tried AT+CWLAP and AT+CWMODE. Both return ERROR.

Comment: Looks like you have some odd (i.e. not the "standard" Espressif) firmware on there. Output of AT+GMR for me is `AT version:1.1.0.0(May 11 2016 18:09:56)` 
`SDK version:1.5.4(baaeaebb)` 
`compile time:May 20 2016 15:06:44` 
`OK` - though, I have flashed the very latest version of the AT firmware, but you can see it outputs a lot more info than just a version number

Comment: Shouldn't flashing ESP8266 again with latest firmware fix your problem? I have this same esp8266 module but I do get proper version info like @jaromanda X